# Android creating buttons like in Play Store app UI with colors and effects

Tags: android, material-design

[image: Play Store app UI]

I need to create buttons and headers using colors and styles similar to play store UI.
How can i create a button using colors alone without using drawables?
When i fill red or green color to the button not getting such effect like in play store app

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example for the buttons showing what you can do using xml only:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_red_round_corners"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Clipboard" />
```

where `button_red_round_corners` is defined in your `drawable` folder as

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#EE0000" />
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
```

Result:
[image: Xml styled button]

The only problem is that there's no touch feedback if you use the `android:background` attribute :-(
There should be a way using [Drawable Selectors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element) though.

Comment: Thanks daniel. But my doubt is how the clipboard pic is displayed adjacent to the text ?

Comment: You can use the `drawablePadding` attribute to add additional space between the icon and the text, and the (regular) `paddingLeft` attribute to control the distance from the left border to the start of the content (i.e. your icon)

Answer (score 0):

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
```

you can add this in your button

```
    <Button ...
....
    />
```

whatever drawable u want to use ,you can put there